# How can I hide the overflow on a div for one image but allow it for another?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains two images. I want the div to have overflow hidden that affects one image but not the other. Is that possible? I was thinking it might go something like this below (which of course doesn't work).

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
}

.no-overflow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.overflow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="no-overflow">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" class="overflow">
</div>
```

Comment: the short answer is no but can you describe your use case. I am pretty sure we can find a solution for what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the parent `.container` has `overflow: hidden;` all overflowing content (including all descendant children's content) will be hidden.

One solution here is to move the element outside the `.container` and use relative positioning to have it overlap the `.container`.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
}

.no-overflow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.overlap {
  position: relative;
  top: -210px;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="no-overflow">
</div>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" class="overlap">
```

Another solution could be to manually clip the child you want partially hidden, while allowing the overflow to be visible.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}

.no-overflow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  /* clip to a 150x130px square with the x y of each corner */
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 150px 0, 150px 130px, 0 130px);
}

.overflow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="no-overflow">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" class="overflow">
</div>
```

Comment: I kind of figured that I would have to move it outside of the container. I have a hero element with a video background that is full width (bootstrap 5), I have a logo and some title and copy text that is set at col-5 with offset-1. I also have a col-2 that contains a second image whose height extends into the section below. I was hoping to keep it all within the grid to have better responsiveness. When I hat it outside of the grid, it acted kind of funny on smaller (tablet screens as one example)